# Deployment of complex addons

Tags: python, add-on, installation

On Blender 2.91.2, windows and linux
Here is my situation:

I have developed an Addon that uses several dependency python libraries.

I first made an "install dependencies" button in the GUI interface of the addon, inspired by [this example](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/tree/master/add_ons/install_dependencies). On windows this requires elevated rights to run, and doesnt work properly on the windows installer version of Blender(only on stand-alone).

To make it more complicated, some of the libraries are not reacheable by pip everywhere, as they are internal libs. This addon is not intended for public use either.

To get these libs working, I simply added them manually to the "/python/lib/python3.7" folder, which worked flawlessly.

To make it even more complicated, in order to run the addon properly, certain settings are required that are not straightforward to do. The most annoying one is to set the default backend to matplotlib to WebAgg, which requires changing a config file in the library location.

Lots of other settings needs to be set as well (that could be done through the python api with effort).

This led me to the approach of deploying using a full stand-alone blender, with all the dependencies installed and with everything configured. The addon itself is simply put in the internal Addon directory: "/2.91/scripts/addons/"

This brings the new difficulty of handling new addons that the user would add to this version. I would like to have a stand-alone system fully, where new addons would be put in a sub-folder to the folder of stand-alone blender.

This doesnt seem to be allowed. In the filepaths option of blender, one can set relative paths only relative to where blender is run from (where the blend file lies, or from where you ran blender on command line). I would need to be able to set relative paths to the Blender binary.

I would like to know if there is a better approach to the above deployment. Preferrably, I would like to not deploy using a configured stand-alone blender install at all, but at the very least i would then want to get this install to have all addons installed put in a sub-folder.